# Rename Site Collection SharePoint Online Using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, rename

How can I rename a site collection on SharePoint online?

For example, I want to change the URL from /sites/foo to /sites/foobar

Is it possible using PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think,if there is a easy way to do it.

- you have to backup site collection
- delete current site collection
- restore site collection on new URL

Or if you are using any migration tools then those can be helpful.

Please check the following URL https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3053838

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear what you mean by rename. If you want to change the URL from `/teams/abc123` to `/teams/def456`, no you cannot do this without migration of the data from one site to another.

If you merely need to change the name of the site from "IT" to "Information Technology", go to the gear, click Site Settings, and click on Title, description, and icon.

Comment: I'll update my question to include the first type of rename that you have given an example of.